# GNU Parallel with -j -N still uses one CPU

Tags: bash, shell-script, for, parallelism, gnu-parallel

How can I get reasonable parallelisation on multi-core nodes without saturating resources? As in many other similar questions, the question is really how to learn to tweak GNU Parallel to get reasonable performance.

In the following example, I can't get to run processes in parallel without saturating resources or everything seems to run in one CPU after using some `-j -N` options.

From inside a Bash script running in a multi-core machine, the following loop is passed to GNU Parallel

```
for BAND in $(seq 1 "$BANDS") ;do
        echo "gdalmerge_and_clean $VARIABLE $YEAR $BAND $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_X $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_Y"
done |parallel
```

This saturates, however, the machine and slows down processing.

In `man parallel` I read

> --jobs -N
> -j -N
> --max-procs -N
> -P -N
>
> Subtract N from the number of CPU threads.
>
> Run this many jobs in parallel.  If the evaluated number is less than 1 then 1
> will be used.
>
> See also: --number-of-threads --number-of-cores --number-of-sockets

and I've tried to use

```
|parallel -j -3
```

but this, for some reason, uses only one CPU out of the 40. Checking with [h]top, only one CPU is reported high-use, the rest down to 0. Should `-j -3` not use 'Number of CPUs' - 3 which would be 37 CPUs for example?

and I extended the previous call then

```
-j -3 --use-cores-instead-of-threads
```

blindly doing so, I guess. I've read https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114678/13011, and I know from the admins of the cluster I used to run such parallel jobs, that *hyperthreading is disabled*. This is still running in one CPU.

I am now trying to use the following:

```
for BAND in $(seq 1 "$BANDS") ;do
        echo "gdalmerge_and_clean $VARIABLE $YEAR $BAND $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_X $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_Y"
done |parallel -j 95%
```

or with `|parallel -j 95% --use-cores-instead-of-threads`.

**Note**

For the record, this is part of a batch job, scheduled via HTCondor and each job running on a separate node with some 40 physical CPUs available.

Above, I kept only the essential -- the complete for loop piped to `parallel` is:

> ```
> for BAND in $(seq 1 "$BANDS") ;do
>    # Do not extract, unscale and merge if the scaled map exists already!
>    SCALED_MAP="era5_and_land_${VARIABLE}_${YEAR}_band_${BAND}_merged_scaled.nc"
>    MERGED_MAP="era5_and_land_${VARIABLE}_${YEAR}_band_${BAND}_merged.nc"
>    if [ ! -f "${SCALED_MAP+set}" ] ;then
>        echo "log $LOG_FILE Action=Merge, Output=$MERGED_MAP, Pixel >size=$OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_X $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_Y, Timestamp=$(timestamp)"
>        echo "gdalmerge_and_clean $VARIABLE $YEAR $BAND $OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_X >$OUTPUT_PIXEL_SIZE_Y"
>    else
>        echo "warning "Scaled map "$SCALED_MAP" exists already! Skipping merging.-""
>    fi
> done |parallel -j 95%
> log "$LOG_FILE" "Action=Merge, End=$(timestamp)"
> ```

```
where `log` and `warning` are a custom functions
```

Comment: Does `parallel` correctly detect your CPU cores ? What does `parallel --number-of-cores` print? Also, does it work as expected if you explicitly specify the no. of cores to be used, e.g. `-j 17` ?

Comment: Yes, `parallel` correctly detects all CPU cores. In one job running in some node, for example, it reports 40. Not all nodes are the same, however. Anyhow, jobs will only be assigned to machines with at least 24 CPUs. The idea behind `-j 95%` was to avoid hardcoding the number of CPUs. Nonetheless, in my latest attempts I just put `-j 20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this I will suggest you first run this with something simpler than `gdalmerge_and_clean`.

Try:

```
seq 100 | parallel 'seq {} 100000000 | gzip | wc -c'
```

Does this correctly run one job per CPU thread?

```
seq 100 | parallel -j 95% 'seq {} 100000000 | gzip | wc -c'
```

Does this correctly run 19 jobs for every 20 CPU threads?

My guess is that `gdalmerge_and_clean` is actually run in the correct number of instances, but that it depends on I/O and is waiting for this. So your disk or network is pushed to the limit while the CPU is sitting idle and waiting.

You can verify the correct number of copies is started by using `ps aux | grep gdalmerge_and_clean`.

You can see if your disks are busy with `iostats -dkx 1`.

Comment: I think you are right. At some point, I observed via [`h`]`top` multiple CPUs kicking-in! I guess when resources weere freed. Background: jobs run in JRC's [BDAP](https://jeodpp.jrc.ec.europa.eu/bdap/) platform, scheduled via HTCondor. Physical machines that compose the cluster offer shared resources to docker containers in which, ideally, one process runs on one CPU. My workflow isn't exactly a fit for an HTC. It would better run in an HPC. Or design a workflow using [DAGMan](https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-manual/dagman-workflows.html). GNU Parallel rocks, however!

Comment: What can be then done from the "user"'s side for network or/and disk I/O bottlenecks? Can GNU Parallel be tweaked in this regard? Or is it irrelevant and outside its territory?

Comment: Also: `grep` correctly shows some 20 jobs now (after `parallel -j 20`.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris You will need to find the optimal number to run in parallel. You do that by increasing the number of jobs in parallel until the average runtime increases.